# how to search over jupyter notebook python files?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have many jupyter python files (ipnyb), how can I easily search over python source code over them, for example from command line or jupyter-notebook client itself? I am looking for something dedicated to jupter notebooks instead of normal find/grep because embedded data " "data": {
      "image/png" }

Answer (score 7):

This command allow you to perform a recursive search (through all directories from the current directory)

For explanations about this command check this link => [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find%20.%20-name%20%27*ipynb%27%20%7C%20xargs%20grep%20print)

```bash
find . -name '*ipynb' | xargs grep 'YOUR SEARCH'
```

Comment: Yes, right, but notebook files often contains embedded additional data like images in section " "data": { "image/png" } ..

Comment: And what's your needs ? Search for these additional datas ?

Comment: if you need to find a special string why not searching for `'"mystring"'` instead of `'mystring'`, I mean adding quotes so you don't get random keyword in a embedded data

Comment: I thought there is a jupyert dedicated tool to do that. Currently I'am using jupyter-nbconvert to convert ipynb to python files and then search over them. Metadata of ipynb is a problem.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking to do this, too!  I found a pretty good solution that you can do from within a notebook.  The [google groups discussion is here](https://groups.google.com/g/jupyter/c/Qi9b7z_sgRU?pli=1), but in case the link breaks, here is the code provided there:

```
pattern = '../**/*.ipynb'
query = 'text you want to find'

for filepath in glob.iglob(pattern, recursive=True):
    with open(filepath) as file:
        s = file.read()
        if (s.find(query) > -1):
            print(filepath)
```

This will print all of the files that contain the search string.  A nice enhancement would be to also print the context in which the string occurs.

Comment: Hi , some time ago I found a solution by myself. There is what I was looking for:

https://github.com/conery/nbscan

but moderator deleted my answer. :-)

Answer (score 4):

To search inside a notebook, use the find+replace shortcut, `F`, in command mode. For example, on Kaggle, `Esc` for command mode, then `F` to trigger find.

Or open command palette with `Cmd+Shift+P` on Mac, `Ctrl+Shift+P` on Linux/Win. Then just type "find" in it.

As for searching over multiple notebooks at once within Jupyter, I have no experience. I suggest looking into JupyterLabs and its extensions, since it seems more geared for multiple notebooks.

From CLI, plain grep works

```
grep wordtosearch *.ipynb
```

For recursion

```
grep -r --include \*.ipynb wordtosearch mytopdirectory
```

Comment: Yes, right, but notebook files often contains embedded additional data like images in section "   "data": {
      "image/png" } ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Shell function (appropriate for adding to your .bashrc file):

```
gfind() { grep -r --include "*$2" "$1" ./ };
```

Then to look recursively over all files in the current directory, run:

```
gfind "words to search"
```

To restrict it to files with a certain extension, run:

```
gfind "words to search" .ipynb
```